# Как проанализировать данные о трудоустройстве?

Tags: анализ-данных

Стоит задача определить качество подготовки ВУЗа, студента которого задействованы в системе по подбору персонала и поиску работы(системы не существует в реальности, это модель, данные выдуманы).
В системе есть данные о дате создания резюме студентом, дате нахождения им работы, также есть данные о том, как работодатель оценивает навыки студента после работы с ним(после увольнения или во время работы).
Работа может быть стажировкой, практикой и просто работой.
Есть вариант использовать *следующие показатели*: процент трудоустроившихся, продолжительность работы, средняя оценка работодателем навыков студента, срок от регистрации до нахождения первой работы.
Довольно хороши показатели из [этой](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/pokazateli-effektivnosti-trudoustroystva-vypusknikov-uchrezhdeniy-professionalnogo-obrazovaniya/viewer) статьи, но проблему обозначил ниже. Да и там в контексте сравнения, что мне тоже необходимо будет делать, однако сначала хотя бы один ВУЗ оценить и перевести в воспринимаемые обычными людьми единицы(проценты, 5-ти балльная шкала или любая другая).
Собственно первая проблема - продолжительность работы отчасти определяется не только тем, как себя проявляет студент, но и видом работы - стажировка, практика и тд. Думаю понятно. Есть вариант изначально делить данные на стажировка/практика/работа и по ним отдельно считать продолжительность каждого вида, но потом проблема - как это собрать воедино, чтобы интерпретировать.
О навыках - оценка довольно объективная, потому что речь о трудоустройстве в IT-сфере - это про soft(коммуникабельность, умение работать в команде и тд) и hard(языки программирования и просто навыки по типу вышмата, бизнес-анализа).
Думал просто находить среднее без выбросов, выбросы определять с помощью 25% и 75% квартилей, затем просто отсекать их.

В общем - какие рекомендации по показателям и по сведению их всех к какому-то интерпретируемому виду, возможно для дальнейшего ранжирования? Куда копать, что искать?

Comment: Ну это целый проект. Вам нужно "нагенерить фич", потом проверить, есть ли у вас "сигнал в данных", дают ли вам эти фичи какую-то предсказательную силу для вашей "целевой переменной", которую тоже ещё нужно грамотно выбрать. И выбор метрики, которой вы будете мерить успешность вашей модели - это тоже отдельное искусство. Так что, повторюсь, это целая работа, целый проект. Надо пробовать всякое, причём в цикле фичи->модель->оценка_качества->снова_фичи... усидчиво и кропотливо. А что делать с выбросами надо думать тогда, когда у вас будут фичи и вы увидите, что выбросы вам реально мешают.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но что такое "нагенерить фич" в данном контексте?

Comment: Это про "придумать тестовые случаи"?

Comment: Это про то, какие взять показатели и что с ними сделать. Не всегда достаточно "сырых" показателей, часто нужно их как-то ещё обработать, извлечь из них дополнительную информацию.